# Html Tags in Xamarin App

Tags: html, xamarin

Is there a way to show HTML Content (Text formatted with HTML Tags) in a Xamarin.Forms App?

If yes, are there Html Tags that are not allowed?

The content comes from a wysiwyg-editor in the web backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`WebView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/webview/) to display HTML. The documentation says

> WebView supports various content sources, including embedded HTML, web pages, and HTML strings.

You could - for example - bind the content to a property

```
<WebView Content="{Binding HtmlContent}" />
```

when the `BindingContext` of the webview or any parent view is set accordingly.

e.g. in your viewmodel (if you are familiar with MVVM)

```
void LoadContent()
{
    var htmlContent = LoadContentFromServer();
    HtmlContent = htmlContent;
}
```

AFAIK there are no *illegal* HTML tags.

Comment: Maybe it should be a good Idea to disable some Html Tags in the web backend to prevent XSS. How is this done in praxis? Maybe by using markdown?

Comment: I don't know your exact use case, but it's conceivable that disabling tags for security makes sense.